# Nuxt 3: How to correctly load third party Javascript for embedding into page (using Eleven Labs API Audio Native widget)

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, elevenlabs

I am trying to integrate the [ElevenLabs Audio Native widget](https://elevenlabs.io/docs/api-reference/creates-audionative-enabled-project) into my Nuxt 3 app programmatically using the API. I have successfully received the correct response from the Elevenlabs server that returns the html widget for embedding on the Nuxt client. However, when embedding on the client (code shown below), I just get a **"Loading the Elevenlabs Text to Speech AudioNative Player..."** text shown. I am guessing the problem is that I am not loading the third party script appropriately.

**Screenshot of Client:**

[image]

**`/components/AudioPlayer.vue`:**

```
<template>
    <section>
        <div v-html="audioHtmlSnippet"></div>
    </section>
</template>

<script setup>
const audioHtmlSnippet = ref('');

const uploadContentAndGetEmbedCode = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    // Append your parameters here as shown in the API example
    formData.append("author", "Author Name")
    formData.append('auto_convert', 'true')
    formData.append('name', 'ProjectTest')
    // Note: For the 'file', ensure you have a file input or similar to get the content
    formData.append("file", new Blob(["<html><body><div><p>The text to test for speech</p><h5>More of your content</h5><p>Some more of your content</p></div></body></html>"], { type: "text/html" }));

    try {
        const response = await $fetch('https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/audio-native', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'xi-api-key': '<REMOVED>'
            },
            body: formData
        });
        console.log(response);
        audioHtmlSnippet.value = response.html_snippet;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};


useHead({
    script: [
        {
            src: 'https://elevenlabs.io/player/audioNativeHelper.js',
            type: 'text/javascript',
            defer: true,
            async: true
        }
    ]
})

onMounted(() => {
    uploadContentAndGetEmbedCode();
})

</script>
```

**Server response from fetch:**

```
{
    "project_id": "erWuc18XuNVO0ljcbcgh",
    "converting": true,
    "html_snippet": "<div id=\"elevenlabs-audionative-widget\" data-height=\"90\" data-width=\"100%\" data-frameborder=\"no\" data-scrolling=\"no\" data-publicuserid=\"280a9e317cdab585abe0ae91fe6890ad69590b9a60007cb90a733f870764d3db\" data-playerurl=\"https://elevenlabs.io/player/index.html\" data-small=\"True\" data-textcolor=\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)\" data-backgroundcolor=\"rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)\" data-projectid=\"erWuc18XuNVO0ljcbcgh\" >Loading the <a href=\"https://elevenlabs.io/text-to-speech\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">Elevenlabs Text to Speech</a> AudioNative Player...</div><script src=\"https://elevenlabs.io/player/audioNativeHelper.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>"
}
```

**Anyone got any ideas on how to get this working correctly and show the audio widget?** Here is the expected output on the UI:

[image]